# How to Change the default properties of ToolBox items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm currently creating a project in Visual Studio 2015 using C# in WinForms; I used the words "ToolBox items" to refer to dateTimePickers, textbox, labels etc. It is a really big project and it will save me a lot of time if I could drag and drop the objects and they  already have format; for example the datetimePicker custom format, textbox align etc.

The issue is that I need to customize some properties of these objects. This far I have this piece of code that allows me to change some properties that are overridable.

```
public partial class MoneyBox : TextBox
{
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get { return Color.Azure;}
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }
}
```

But for other properties I cannot do this. Also I cannot inherit from an object already formatted because this object hasn't been initialized and I get null when inheriting. I also tried to customize the initialize component and the paint event of objects, but for some reason the changes don't show on the object.

```
public partial class DateTimePick : DateTimePicker
{
    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        this.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Copying and pasting the toolbox item should retain the set properties.

Comment: It just does not require properties to be overridable.  Redefining the property with the `new` keyword works very well too, the designer does not have a problem with it.  Reflection allows it to always find the correct one.  And of course you can always add your own.  InitializeComponent() generally only makes sense if Form or UserControl is the base class.

Comment: @HansPassant didn't really undestand what you meant.

Comment: For most cases, you can initialize properties in constructor of the control. For some cases like `Text` property, when you drop the control on design surface, values will be set in  `InitializeNewComponent` method of `Designer` of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor is a suitable place to initialize properties of the control. For most properties, to initialize the control with custom values when you drop it on design surface, it's enough to set new values in constructor, for example:

```
public class MyDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    public MyDateTimePicker()
    {
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        this.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}
```

In some cases, for example for `Text` property, when you drop an instance of the control on design surface, the property is set in `InitializeNewComponent` method of the `Designer` of control.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, I'm sure there is a better way of doing it, but this was my solution for default control properties. It makes a list of all controls in your form (and their child controls) and changes the properties on initialization.

```
   public static void ChangeDefaultProperties(Control C)     
   {
        var ControlQueue = new Queue<Control>();
        ControlQueue.Enqueue(C);
        while (ControlQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            Control Current = ControlQueue.Dequeue();

            DefaultPropertiesOverride(Current);
            foreach (Control c in Current.Controls)
            {
                ControlQueue.Enqueue(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DefaultPropertiesOverride(Control C)
    {
        if(C is DateTimePicker)
        {
            ((DateTimePicker)C).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            ((DateTimePicker)C).CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        }
        if(C is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)C).BackColor = Color.Azure;
        }
    }
```

Then just call ChangeDefaultProperties(this); in your main form initialization